Oracle : Import CSV file using SQL script in SQL Developer
I have at least 20 CSV files to import to different 20 tables, one CSV file for each table. Is there any step to import the CSV file, without using SQL-Loader (GUI or Script) or IMPDP? Only using SQL script, also to generate all the columns too from all the tables would be greatly appreciated, because all the method I found only use SQL*Loader or IMPDP.
For note, my method to export using spool that can generate select * from all the 20 of different tables

Yes, use sqlcl and the load command. https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/09/sqlcl-and-the-load-csv-command/

yeah, I read your blog about sqlcl before. and I already try typing "help load" on my sqlplus. but got error "SP2-0172: No HELP matching this topic was found." what's wrong with my installer?

As stated on the Jeff's blog page: "a command in SQLcl that is NOT in SQL*Plus) commands is ‘LOAD.’"... you have to install sqlcl tool… https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/sqlcl/

Sqlcl is not sqlplus, it's a modern replacement

"replacement"... based on Java it still has some limitations - same as SQLDeveloper... like not supporting queries containing question marks you may have in patterns (regexp, match_recognize, ...): the "Non Supported SQL92 Token at Position:" error...

I tried install sqlcl but got error "Incompatible version of libocijdbc [Jdbc:211200230906, Jdbc-OCI:2115000] using instant client 21.15, but If I upgrade to instant client 23.4, I got error "No ocijdbc21 in java.library.path"

replacement yes, you just need to escape the ? marks @p3consulting

@DonnyAlexander remove $ORACLE_HOME from your path, it's trying to pull in the sqlnet binaries and that's not necessary

@thatjeffsmith, and how do you escape the ? in a match_recognize expression like "PATTERN ( ^ not_disconnect {- any_row*? disconnect -} )" ? In JDBC, you do statement.setEscapeProcessing(false), in DBeaver, TOAD, SQL*Plus it works as is but not in SQLcl or SQLDeveloper or VSCode with Oracle extension... And even f you can escape it, it would mean you need 2 versions of the same script depending on the tool used to execute it...

@p3consulting ask as a question, and i'll provide an answer

@thatjeffsmith hello, for this task, I think I should stick using script, by using spool - select /*insert*/ * from, because it will use for our engineer in client. But for me as DBA, I will learn how to use SQLcl  and  external tables. I will learn from your blog. Thank you for your advice

Create external tables for each CSV file and then read them using plain old SQL. The Oracle Documentation has some good examples...
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/examples-using-oracle-external-tables.html#GUID-53C71354-FDC0-4CD7-BBF1-2B7327A1A245

hello, for this task, I think I should stick using script, by using spool - select /insert/ * from, because it will use for our engineer in client. But for me as DBA, I will learn how to use external tables. Thank you
